# Bulk actions in paginated table

Tags: tables, bulk

I have a paginated table of items. We can do some bulk actions ( like delete) on items.
User selects some items on page 1 and goes to next page and selects some items on page 2.
is it better that bulk actions work per page? Or work on all selected items in all pages?

Comment: Gmail apparently does it for all entries. See [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/124329/best-approach-to-update-all-entries-in-a-list-that-is-paginated)

Answer (score 1):

Bulk actions should work on all selected items. If you let the user select some items on first page, some on second, and then do the action only for the items from the first page, that would be confusing.

I think that displaying the number of the selected items would help.
Also, while doing the bulk action, there can be some information provided to the user:
a) in progress bar, eg. "Deleting 52 items"
b) on the modal, eg. "You're going to delete 52 items. Are you sure?"